# Why fetch first 10 rows and select all rows cost same?

Tags: sql, db2

I have below query with db2 and want to fetch first 10 rows from the result , but I noticed that the execute time and explain cost same for fetch 10 rows only and fetch all rows , why this happen?

```
select this_.RIGHTSID as y0_
     , this_.RIGHTSNUM as y1_
     , rightstype1_.NAME as y2_
     , rightsstat3_.NAME as y3_
     , this_.ISSUEDATE as y4_
     , this_.EXPIRYDATE as y5_
     , licensee4_.NAME as y6_
     , agency2_.NAME as y7_
     , agency2_.AGENCYID as y8_
     , this_.EFFECTIVEDATE as y9_
     , rightstype1_.RIGHTSTYPEID as y10_ 
from RIGHTS_TB this_ 
inner join RIGHTS_TYPE_TB rightstype1_ on this_.RIGHTSTYPEID=rightstype1_.RIGHTSTYPEID
inner join AGENCY_TB agency2_ on rightstype1_.AGENCYID=agency2_.AGENCYID 
inner join RIGHTS_STATUS_TB rightsstat3_ on this_.RIGHTSSTATUSID=rightsstat3_.RIGHTSSTATUSID 
inner join LICENSEE_TB licensee4_ on this_.LICENSEEID=licensee4_.LICENSEEID 
where this_.ACTIVE_IND='Y'
order by this_.ISSUEDATE desc 
    fetch first 10 rows only
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in total? Fetching may only be a very small part of the execution cost (which could involve on-disk sorting for all we know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms, all of this is performed:

```
select this_.RIGHTSID as y0_
     , this_.RIGHTSNUM as y1_
     , rightstype1_.NAME as y2_
     , rightsstat3_.NAME as y3_
     , this_.ISSUEDATE as y4_
     , this_.EXPIRYDATE as y5_
     , licensee4_.NAME as y6_
     , agency2_.NAME as y7_
     , agency2_.AGENCYID as y8_
     , this_.EFFECTIVEDATE as y9_
     , rightstype1_.RIGHTSTYPEID as y10_ 
FROM RIGHTS_TB this_ 
    inner join RIGHTS_TYPE_TB rightstype1_ on this_.RIGHTSTYPEID=rightstype1_.RIGHTSTYPEID
    inner join AGENCY_TB agency2_ on rightstype1_.AGENCYID=agency2_.AGENCYID 
    inner join RIGHTS_STATUS_TB rightsstat3_ on this_.RIGHTSSTATUSID=rightsstat3_.RIGHTSSTATUSID 
    inner join LICENSEE_TB licensee4_ on this_.LICENSEEID=licensee4_.LICENSEEID 
WHERE this_.ACTIVE_IND='Y' 
ORDER BY this_.ISSUEDATE desc
```

before this can be performed:

```
fetch first 10 rows only
```

It isn't possible to know which records are allowed until the full FROM and WHERE clauses are completed, then you cannot know which fit into the FIRST n until the ORDER is completed too

So it isn't at all surprising that the execution time is similar.

Comment: An index on (issueDate, active_ind) could do away with the sorting.